# Add row to a dataframe conditionally

Tags: r

Hi I have n data frame that I open sequentially with a for loop

```
myfiles <- list.files(pattern="*.dat")
myfilesContent <- lapply(myfiles, read.table, header=T, quote="\"")
for (i in 1:length(myfiles)){
 ...
}
```

What I would like to do is to open only the one that are respecting a certain condition and merging them by row, like

```
df <- data.frame
for (i in 1:length(myfiles)){
  if(unique(myfilesContent[[i]]$V1) %in% test) df <-merge(df,myfilesContent[[i]])
}
```

but I get this error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class '"function"' into a data.frame
```

Many thanks

Comment: The error is because `df<- data.frame` assigns `df` to the `data.frame(...)` *function*. Later, you reference it as if is was a variable, hence the error. If you want to create an empty data frame, use `df<-data.frame()`. However, the answer below from @agstudy is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for example:

```
  do.call(rbind,lapply(myfiles, function(x){
          dt <- read.table(x, header=TRUE, quote="\"")
          if (dt$V1 %in% test) dt 
   }))
```

You read and you keep only thoses verifying the condition. Then you bind the result.